# Is it possible to deploy jar from AWS S3 bucket directly to cloudfoundry?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud-foundry

I have a local server with cloud foundry. And I have my artifact file stored into aws s3 bucket. So is it possible to do something like "cf push s3://bucket/folder/test.jar" or similar kind of thing that will directly deploy the jar file from s3 bucket into cloud foundry (without downloading the jar to local)? I have all the credentials required to connect to s3 in manifest.yml file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure, but you definitely can mount your s3 like fuse fs and push your jar. https://tecadmin.net/mount-s3-bucket-centosrhel-ubuntu-using-s3fs/

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can only push from your local filesystem.

The closest I think you could get, at the time I write this, would be to `cf push` some marker file & use a custom buildpack, which detects the marker file, to download your JAR files from S3 during staging.  That's a lot of work though.

The easiest thing would be to download and push (or mount your S3 locally).  If you have slow Internet, it's probably better to just get a VM on AWS and push from there, or set up CI and let it deploy for you.

Hope that helps!